# Get next int from array

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a button that when clicked will cause a thread to sleep for x amount of time.

I would like the thread to get the amount of time from an array.

This is what should happen:

1. The button is clicked, the first number is selected
2. The thread sleeps then does its thing
3. After its done what it needs to do the next number is selected and the process repeats until there are no more numbers.

The code I have so far is:

```
private int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 3, 6, 2, 5};

public void myMethod() {
    try {
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
           x = intArray[i];
        }

        Thread.sleep(x);

        // my custom things happen here after the thread sleep

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RoutePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting `int i = 0` every time this method is called. You might want to make it a field instead and give it a meaningful name.

Comment: Is something not working? It looks fine to me. If you want `Thread.sleep(x)` to be in seconds you'll want to multiply those integers by 1000 since it is in ms. Also you would want to put the `sleep` inside the for loop.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(millis)` will be too fast for you to see if your delay is less than 20 milliseconds.

Comment: `x` will always be `5`...

Comment: @cricket_007 You are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sleep` and the "custom thing" should be inside the `for` loop.

```
private int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 3, 6, 2, 5};
public void myMethod() {
  try {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
      x = intArray[i];
      Thread.sleep(x);
      // my custom things happen here after the thread sleep
   }
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RoutePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
       x = intArray[i];
    }

    Thread.sleep(x);
```

This code iterates through the entire array, and overwrites the value of `x` each time, *always* leaving `x` set to the last value encountered (which in your case is `5`.

```
sleep(5);
```

sleeps for 5 *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the premise of your question, this will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException every time. intArray.length may give 5, but intArray[5] gives the exception because it doesn't exist.  Since arrays are zero-based, you have intArray[0] - intArray[4] available, so use intArray.length-1.

Now, as to your question, even if you did have intArray[5] available, it would sleep that long every time, because the loop completes and the last assigned value for x would be the last element of the array.

1. Remove the loop
2. Move the instantiation of x outside of myMethod()
3. Increment x every time the button is clicked

Be sure to check (x == intArray.length) and, if so, assign x = 0.  Otherwise you'll get that ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException again.

P.S. Thread.sleep() takes milliseconds, so if you want seconds use 4000, 3000, 6000, 2000, 5000, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have more than one problem:

> Get next int from array

That's easy.  The problem is that you need a *persistent* variable (i.e., not a local variable in some event handler) to remember the index of the next entry in the array:

```
private int[] intArray = new int[]{4, 3, 6, 2, 5};
private int next_index = 0;

private boolean hasNext() {
    return next_index < intArray.length;
}

private int getNext() {
    return intArray[next_index++];
}
```

---

> I have a button that when clicked will cause a thread to sleep for x amount of time.

That sounds like a bad idea.  More specifically, "cause a thread to sleep" is not something that one thread can do to another.  A thread can cause *itself* to sleep by calling `Thread.sleep(nnnn)`.

But `Thread.sleep()` is not something that you should do inside an event handler because your program will not be able to respond to any events (i.e., it will appear to be "locked up" or "hung") until the handler returns.

If you want a button press to make something happen n seconds later, the right way to do that is to use a timer.

It looks something like this (But please excuse any mistakes, I don't normally write Swing code):

```
int numMilliseconds = getNext() * 1000;
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(
        numMilliseconds,
        (ActionEvent e) -> makeSomethingHappen(...)
        );
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```